# %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) meaning

Tags: visual-c++, macros

Think this will be rather simple but somehow I could not find a reference saying about this.

In the MSVC Include directories, there is an Additional Include Directories setting. The setting reads like this

..\Project1; %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)

Understand the first part is the path for the program to search for additional program header includes. What about " %(AdditionalIncludeDirectories) " ? what does it mean?

It does not seem to be a macro which I understand is headed by "$" eg $MACRO

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

### Answer

In [the documentation for Working with Project Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/669zx6zc.aspx) there is a section on "item macros":

#### Item macros

Has the syntax **%(name)**. For a file, an item macro applies only to that file—for example, you can use **%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)** to specify include directories that apply only to a particular file. This kind of item macro corresponds to an **ItemGroup** metadata in MSBuild. When it's used in the context of a project configuration, an item macro applies to all files of a certain type. For example, the C/C++ **Preprocessor Definitions** configuration property can take a **%(PreprocessorDefinitions)** item macro that applies to all .cpp files in the project. This kind of item macro corresponds to an **ItemDefinitionGroup** metadata in MSBuild. For more information, see [Item Definitions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb651788.aspx).

### Discussion

I had exactly the same problem in a project I am taking over from a former developer : his Additional Include Directories are `C:\Users\t-tshmit\Downloads\DirectXTK;$(ProjectDir);$(IntermediateOutputPath);%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)`

[image: Additional Include Directories flyout]

And oddly the `%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` element is not included in the edit box

[image: Edit box for Additional Include Directories]

Looking around the web I could not find much on this, but it is clearly a pattern in use, for example the screenshot used in http://www.steptools.com/support/stdev_docs/help/settings_vc10.html may contain the `%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories)` element.

The documentation for both the [Additional Include Directories compiler options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w.aspx) and the [AdditionalIncludeDirectories VCCL Compiler Tool property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcclcompilertool.additionalincludedirectories.aspx) contain no mention of this `%(NAME)` pattern.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/common-macros-for-build-commands-and-properties?view=vs-2019

They are called "item metadata macros."

> The build system for C++ was significantly changed between Visual
>   Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2010. Many macros used in earlier
>   project types have been changed to new ones. These macros are no
>   longer used or have been replaced by one or more equivalent properties
>   or item metadata macro (%(name)) values. Macros that are marked
>   "migrated" can be updated by the project migration tool. If the
>   project that contains the macro is migrated from Visual Studio 2008 or
>   earlier to Visual Studio 2010, Visual Studio converts the macro to the
>   equivalent current macro. Later versions of Visual Studio can't
>   convert projects from Visual Studio 2008 and earlier to the new
>   project type. You must convert these projects in two steps; first
>   convert them to Visual Studio 2010, and then convert the result to
>   your newer version of Visual Studio. For more information, see
>   Overview of potential upgrade issues.